# Integrating a hedgehog

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

As motivation of the title, consider the shape of the function $e^{-x}\left(x+\lfloor x\rfloor^2\right)$ as [plotted by WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20e%5E(-x)(x%2B(floor(x))%5E2),%20for%200%3Cx%3C6):

[image]

This exercise I believe that is very easy, let $\lfloor x\rfloor$ the floor function (... obviously we combine with this function when we want to define an integral of the kind hedgehog), then

$$\int_0^6 e^{-x}\left(x+\lfloor x\rfloor^2\right)dx=\sum_{k=1}^6\left(\int_{k-1}^k xe^{-x}dx+(k-1)^2\int_{k-1}^ke^{-x}dx\right),$$ by integrating by part the first summand we get $$\sum_{k=1}^6\left(e^{-k+1}-ke^{-k+1}+ke^{-k}-2e^{-k}-k^2e^{-k}+k^2e^{-k+1}\right)\approx 2.13235.$$
Truly Wolfram Alpha online calculator get the closed-form and agree with my calculations. I know that it is using geometric series (and variation of those), if you want to see the closed-form and get the comparison type these codes, first the integral

> integrate e^(-x)(x+(floor(x))^2)dx, from x=0 to x=6

and secondly the finite sum that we've obtained

> sum e^(-k+1)-k e^(-k+1)+k e^(-k)-2 e^(-k)-k^2 e^(-k)+k^2 e^(-k+1), from k=1 to k=6

Now this question, maybe isn't important but I believe that it is a nice exercise with the purpose to be in a good mood

> **Question.** Can you calculate as a closed-form with all details the infinite case of an integral for a hedgehog, this
>   $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(x+\lfloor x\rfloor^2\right)dx?$$
>   If you believe that isn't feasible get a closed-form, you can provide us your approximation.
>   **Thanks a lot.**

Comment: Many thanks to Lovsovs and @Rahul

Comment: nice question! (+1)

Comment: The hedgehog is earning the reputation, not I, it has the merit. Many thanks I hope that other users ask in a next future about integrals of this kind @tired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A piece is trivial, $\int_{0}^{+\infty}xe^{-x}\,dx=1$. The other piece equals

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor^2 e^{-x}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}n^2 e^{-(x+n)}\,dx =\frac{e(e+1)}{(e-1)^3}\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x}\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{e+1}{(e-1)^2}}.$$

Comment: Where does the factor of $x^2$ in the first equivalency come from? Shouldn't that be $\sum_n n^2\int_{0}^1 e^{-(x+n)}$?

Comment: You are incredible... or you've calculated this integral before than me in your free time. Many thanks.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: correct, fixed.